# Commas containing this phrase?

Tags: sentence-structure

> I do not think, sir, you have any right to command me, **merely because you are older than I**, or because you have seen more of the world than I have; your claim to superiority depends on the use you have made of your time and experience.
>   ― Charlotte Brontë, Jane Eyre

Why may *merely because you are older than I* get contained in commas? Does it get utilized like some phrase? May it seem an adverbial phrase? I may get a comma follows that conjunction *or*.

Comment: There are no hard-and-fast rules about punctuation; every author points differently, and every publisher changes the author's punctuation to suit the "rules" of the publishing house. Moreover, punctuation changes over time; this work was published in 1847, when the fashion called for much denser punctuation than we use today: it tended to follow the rhythm of speech rather than formally marking syntax.

Comment: @StoneyB, will you please write an answer to this question? Pretty please?

Comment: @StoneyB, I second Lucian Sava's comment. please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a parenthetical phrase. A parenthetical phrase, sometimes called simply a parenthetical, is one that is not essential to the framing sentence. In the preceding sentence, the phrase “sometimes called simply a parenthetical” is itself a parenthetical because the segments of the sentence that precede and follow it can be attached to form a complete sentence without it: “A parenthetical phrase is one that is not essential to the framing sentence.”

http://www.dailywritingtips.com/8-types-of-parenthetical-phrases/

Comment: Note that the parenthetical contains all the way to "more of the world than I have" — it doesn't end at the first comma.